# server-derived role based on FilterId using freeradius not working

Tags: authentication, freeradius

I'm setting up a wireless lab. User `guest123` with password `guest123` 
authenticates over wireless using `802.1X` authentication. FreeRadius should 
also return `FilterId=>labguest`. A rule at the wireless controller sets the 
user role to whatever `FilterId` is returned during the `RADIUS` exchange.

Instead, the request/response churns ten times, and the user is assigned the 
default role, `"authenticated"`.

The brief questions before launching into details is what am I doing wrong, 
and is there an automated tool to parse through `FreeRadius -X` output and 
produce recommendations?

Simple command line tests from the wireless controller and freeradius show 
both authentication and returned attributes.

### Here's the part that works

#### From freeradius:

```
root@ubuntu/etc/freeradius@ radtest guest123 guest123 localhost 0 testing123  
    User-Name = "guest123"  
    User-Password = "guest123"  
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1  
    NAS-Port = 0  
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00  
    Cleartext-Password = "guest123"  
Received Access-Accept Id 184 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 0.0.0.0:0 length 36  
    Service-Type = Framed-User  
    Filter-Id = "labguest"
```

#### From Aruba controller:

The role "labguest" is defined here:

```
user-role labguest  
    access-list session global-sacl  
    access-list session apprf-labguest-sacl  
    access-list session "Cant ping controller"  
    access-list session allowall  
    access-list session v6-allowall
```

The rule to assign user role based on FilterId is here:

```
aaa server-group "lab-emp_srvgrp-kqh72"
    auth-server radius1
    set role condition Filter-Id value-of
```

### Here's the part that is broken

After authenticating over wireless and 802.1X, the user receives the default 
802.1X role, "authenticated" rather than "labguest".

```
(Master1) # show user mac 44:39:c4:59:e5:64  
    Name: guest123, IP: 192.168.16.23, MAC: 44:39:c4:59:e5:64, Age: 00:00:05  
    Role: authenticated (how: ROLE_DERIVATION_DOT1X), ACL: 70/0  
    Authentication: Yes, status: successful, method: 802.1x, protocol: EAP-PEAP, server: radius1  
    Authentication Servers: dot1x authserver: radius1, mac authserver:  
    Bandwidth = No Limit  
    Bandwidth = No Limit  
    Role Derivation: ROLE_DERIVATION_DOT1X  
    VLAN Derivation: Default VLAN  
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.15  
<<<deleted debug output>>> 
# Loading authenticate {...}  
# Loading authorize {...}  
# Loading preacct {...}  
# Loading accounting {...}  
# Loading post-proxy {...}  
# Loading post-auth {...}  
# server default  
radiusd: #### Opening IP addresses and Ports ####  
listen {  
    type = "auth"  
    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1  
    port = 18120  
}  
listen {  
    type = "auth"  
    ipaddr = *  
    port = 0  
    limit {  
        max_connections = 16  
        lifetime = 0  
        idle_timeout = 30  
    }  
}  
listen {  
    type = "acct"  
    ipaddr = *  
    port = 0  
    limit {  
        max_connections = 16  
        lifetime = 0  
        idle_timeout = 30  
   }  
}  
listen {  
    type = "auth"  
    ipv6addr = ::  
    port = 0  
    limit {  
        max_connections = 16  
        lifetime = 0  
        idle_timeout = 30  
    }  
}  
listen {
    type = "acct"  
    ipv6addr = ::  
    port = 0  
    limit {  
        max_connections = 16  
        lifetime = 0  
        idle_timeout = 30  
    }  
}  
Listening on auth address 127.0.0.1 port 18120 bound to server inner-tunnel  
Listening on auth address * port 1812 bound to server default  
Listening on acct address * port 1813 bound to server default  
Listening on auth address :: port 1812 bound to server default  
Listening on acct address :: port 1813 bound to server default  
Listening on proxy address * port 50900  
Listening on proxy address :: port 60069  
Ready to process requests  
(0) Received Access-Request Id 42 from 192.168.18.254:40607 to  
192.168.18.249:1812 length 175  
(0)   User-Name = "guest123"  
(0)   NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.18.254  
(0)   NAS-Port = 0  
(0)   NAS-Identifier = "192.168.18.254"  
(0)   NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11  
(0)   Calling-Station-Id = "4439C459E564"  
(0)   Called-Station-Id = "000B86BE91F0"  
(0)   Service-Type = Framed-User  
(0)   Framed-MTU = 1100  
(0)   EAP-Message = 0x0202000d016775657374313233  
(0)   Aruba-Essid-Name = "lab-emp"  
(0)   Aruba-Location-Id = "AP1"  
(0)   Aruba-AP-Group = "lab1"  
(0)   Message-Authenticator = 0x6780aa98cfe6f147e8334301882c9c1f  
(0) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled  
/default  
(0)   authorize {  
(0)     policy filter_username {  
(0)       if (&User-Name) {  
(0)       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE  
(0)       if (&User-Name)  {  
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {  
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE  
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {  
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE  
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {  
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> FALSE  
(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {  
(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))   ->   
FALSE  
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {  
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)   -> FALSE  
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {  
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)   -> FALSE  
(0)       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound  
(0)     } # policy filter_username = notfound  
(0)     [preprocess] = ok  
(0)     [chap] = noop  
(0)     [mschap] = noop  
(0)     [digest] = noop  
(0) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"  
(0) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "guest123", looking up realm NULL  
(0) suffix: No such realm "NULL"  
(0)     [suffix] = noop  
(0) eap: Peer sent EAP Response (code 2) ID 2 length 13  
(0) eap: EAP-Identity reply, returning 'ok' so we can short-circuit the rest  
of authorize  
(0)     [eap] = ok  
(0)   } # authorize = ok  
(0) Found Auth-Type = eap  
(0) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default  
(0)   authenticate {  
(0) eap: Peer sent packet with method EAP Identity (1)  
(0) eap: Calling submodule eap_ttls to process data  
(0) eap_ttls: Initiating new EAP-TLS session  
(0) eap_ttls: [eaptls start] = request  
(0) eap: Sending EAP Request (code 1) ID 3 length 6  
(0) eap: EAP session adding &reply:State = 0xedb76556edb4700e  
(0)     [eap] = handled  
(0)   } # authenticate = handled  
(0) Using Post-Auth-Type Challenge  
(0) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default  
(0)   Challenge { ... } # empty sub-section is ignored  
(0) Sent Access-Challenge Id 42 from 192.168.18.249:1812 to  
192.168.18.254:40607 length 0  
(0)   EAP-Message = 0x010300061520  
(0)   Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000  
(0)   State = 0xedb76556edb4700e88dcdd844646037b  
(0) Finished request  
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.  
(1) Received Access-Request Id 43 from 192.168.18.254:40607 to  
192.168.18.249:1812 length 186  
(1)   User-Name = "guest123"  
(1)   NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.18.254  
(1)   NAS-Port = 0  
(1)   NAS-Identifier = "192.168.18.254"  
(1)   NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11  
(1)   Calling-Station-Id = "4439C459E564"  
(1)   Called-Station-Id = "000B86BE91F0"  
(1)   Service-Type = Framed-User  
(1)   Framed-MTU = 1100  
(1)   EAP-Message = 0x020300060319  
(1)   State = 0xedb76556edb4700e88dcdd844646037b  
(1)   Aruba-Essid-Name = "lab-emp"  
(1)   Aruba-Location-Id = "AP1"  
(1)   Aruba-AP-Group = "lab1"  
(1)   Message-Authenticator = 0xfe39826a334b5ddbe8fa4012037a87d8  
(1) session-state: No cached attributes  
(1) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled  
/default  
(1)   authorize {  
(1)     policy filter_username {  
(1)       if (&User-Name) {  
(1)       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE  
(1)       if (&User-Name)  {  
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {  
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE  
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {  
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE  
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {  
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> FALSE  
(1)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {  
(1)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))   ->   
FALSE  
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {  
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)   -> FALSE  
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {  
(1)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)   -> FALSE  
(1)       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound  
(1)     } # policy filter_username = notfound  
(1)     [preprocess] = ok  
(1)     [chap] = noop  
(1)     [mschap] = noop  
(1)     [digest] = noop  
(1) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"  
(1) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "guest123", looking up realm NULL  
(1) suffix: No such realm "NULL"  
(1)     [suffix] = noop  
(1) eap: Peer sent EAP Response (code 2) ID 3 length 6    
(1) eap: No EAP Start, assuming it's an on-going EAP conversation  
(1)     [eap] = updated  
(1) files: users: Matched entry guest123 at line 82  
(1)     [files] = ok  
(1) sql: EXPAND %{User-Name}  
(1) sql:    --> guest123  
(1) sql: SQL-User-Name set to 'guest123'  
rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection     (0)  
(1) sql: EXPAND SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck  
WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id  
(1) sql:    --> SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck  
WHERE username = 'guest123' ORDER BY id  
(1) sql: Executing select query: SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op  
FROM radcheck WHERE username = 'guest123' ORDER BY id  
rlm_sql_postgresql: Status: PGRES_TUPLES_OK  
rlm_sql_postgresql: query affected rows = 0 , fields = 5  
(1) sql: EXPAND SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username = '%{SQL-  
User-Name}' ORDER BY priority  
(1) sql:    --> SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username =  
'guest123' ORDER BY priority  
(1) sql: Executing select query: SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE  
username = 'guest123' ORDER BY priority  
rlm_sql_postgresql: Status: PGRES_TUPLES_OK  
rlm_sql_postgresql: query affected rows = 0 , fields = 1  
(1) sql: User not found in any groups  
rlm_sql (sql): Released connection     (0)  
Need 5 more connections to reach 10 spares  
rlm_sql (sql): Opening additional connection (5), 1 of 27 pending slots used  
rlm_sql_postgresql: Connecting using parameters: dbname=radius  
host=localhost user=radius password=********  
Connected to database 'radius' on 'localhost' server version 90510, protocol  
version 3, backend PID 1714  
(1)     [sql] = notfound  
(1)     [expiration] = noop  
(1)     [logintime] = noop  
(1) pap: WARNING: Auth-Type already set.  Not setting to PAP  
(1)     [pap] = noop  
(1)   } # authorize = updated  
(1) Found Auth-Type = eap  
(1) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default  
(1)   authenticate {  
(1) eap: Expiring EAP session with state 0xedb76556edb4700e  
(1) eap: Finished EAP session with state 0xedb76556edb4700e  
(1) eap: Previous EAP request found for state 0xedb76556edb4700e, released  
from the list  
(1) eap: Peer sent packet with method EAP NAK (3)  
(1) eap: Found mutually acceptable type PEAP (25)  
(1) eap: Calling submodule eap_peap to process data  
(1) eap_peap: Initiating new EAP-TLS session  
(1) eap_peap: [eaptls start] = request  
(1) eap: Sending EAP Request (code 1) ID 4 length 6  
(1) eap: EAP session adding &reply:State = 0xedb76556ecb37c0e  
(1)     [eap] = handled  
(1)   } # authenticate = handled  
(1) Using Post-Auth-Type Challenge  
(1) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default  
(1)   Challenge { ... } # empty sub-section is ignored  
(1) Sent Access-Challenge Id 43 from 192.168.18.249:1812 to  
192.168.18.254:40607 length 0  
(1)   Service-Type = Framed-User  
(1)   Framed-Filter-Id = "labguest"  
(1)   EAP-Message = 0x010400061920  
(1)   Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000  
(1)   State = 0xedb76556ecb37c0e88dcdd844646037b  
(1) Finished request  
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.  
<<<deleted generally repeating debug output>>>  
(10) Received Access-Request Id 52 from 192.168.18.254:40607 to 192.168.18.249:1812 length 223  
(10)   User-Name = "guest123"  
(10)   NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.18.254  
(10)   NAS-Port = 0  
(10)   NAS-Identifier = "192.168.18.254"  
(10)   NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11  
(10)   Calling-Station-Id = "4439C459E564"  
(10)   Called-Station-Id = "000B86BE91F0"  
(10)   Service-Type = Framed-User  
(10)   Framed-MTU = 1100  
(10)   EAP-Message =  
0x020c002b190017030100209568f164a54cf0e2aa3c<<<more deleted>>>  
(10)   State = 0xedb76556e4bb7c0e88dcdd844646037b  
(10)   Aruba-Essid-Name = "lab-emp"  
(10)   Aruba-Location-Id = "AP1"  
(10)   Aruba-AP-Group = "lab1"  
(10)   Message-Authenticator = 0x2277c43d40495abc84afcfee2d7af56b  
(10) session-state: No cached attributes  
(10) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled  
/default  
(10)   authorize {  
(10)     policy filter_username {  
(10)       if (&User-Name) {  
(10)       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE  
(10)       if (&User-Name)  {  
(10)         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {  
(10)         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE  
(10)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {  
(10)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE  
(10)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {  
(10)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> FALSE  
(10)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {  
(10)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))   ->  
FALSE  
(10)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {  
(10)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)   -> FALSE  
(10)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {  
(10)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)   -> FALSE  
(10)       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound  
(10)     } # policy filter_username = notfound  
(10)     [preprocess] = ok  
(10)     [chap] = noop  
(10)     [mschap] = noop  
(10)     [digest] = noop  
(10) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"  
(10) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "guest123", looking up realm NULL  
(10) suffix: No such realm "NULL"  
(10)     [suffix] = noop  
(10) eap: Peer sent EAP Response (code 2) ID 12 length 43  
(10) eap: Continuing tunnel setup  
(10)     [eap] = ok  
(10)   } # authorize = ok  
(10) Found Auth-Type = eap  
(10) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default  
(10)   authenticate {  
(10) eap: Expiring EAP session with state 0xedb76556e4bb7c0e  
(10) eap: Finished EAP session with state 0xedb76556e4bb7c0e  
(10) eap: Previous EAP request found for state 0xedb76556e4bb7c0e, released  
from the list  
(10) eap: Peer sent packet with method EAP PEAP (25)  
(10) eap: Calling submodule eap_peap to process data  
(10) eap_peap: Continuing EAP-TLS  
(10) eap_peap: [eaptls verify] = ok  
(10) eap_peap: Done initial handshake  
(10) eap_peap: [eaptls process] = ok  
(10) eap_peap: Session established.  Decoding tunneled attributes  
(10) eap_peap: PEAP state send tlv success  
(10) eap_peap: Received EAP-TLV response  
(10) eap_peap: Success  
(10) eap: Sending EAP Success (code 3) ID 12 length 4  
(10) eap: Freeing handler  
(10)     [eap] = ok  
(10)   } # authenticate = ok  
(10) # Executing section post-auth from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled  
/default  
(10)   post-auth {  
(10)     update {  
(10)       No attributes updated  
(10)     } # update = noop  
(10) sql: EXPAND .query  
(10) sql:    --> .query  
(10) sql: Using query template 'query'  
rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection (4)  
(10) sql: EXPAND %{User-Name}  
(10) sql:    --> guest123  
(10) sql: SQL-User-Name set to 'guest123'  
(10) sql: EXPAND INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply, authdate)  
VALUES ( '%{SQL-User-Name}', '%{%{User-Password}:-%{Chap-Password}}',  
'%{reply:Packet-Type}', '%S')  
(10) sql:    --> INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply, authdate)  
VALUES ( 'guest123', ', 'Access-Accept', '2017-12-06 05:15:26')  
(10) sql: Executing query: INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply,  
authdate) VALUES ( 'guest123', ', 'Access-Accept', '2017-12-06 05:15:26')  
rlm_sql_postgresql: Status: PGRES_COMMAND_OK  
rlm_sql_postgresql: query affected rows = 1  
(10) sql: SQL query returned: success  
(10) sql: 1 record(s) updated  
rlm_sql (sql): Released connection (4)  
(10)     [sql] = ok  
(10)     [exec] = noop  
(10)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {  
(10)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {  
(10)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE  
(10)       else {  
(10)         [noop] = noop  
(10)       } # else = noop  
(10)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop  
(10)   } # post-auth = ok  
(10) Sent Access-Accept Id 52 from 192.168.18.249:1812 to  
192.168.18.254:40607 length 0  
(10)   MS-MPPE-Recv-Key =  
0xa5ded2c64f1026f75e105877bcc5715f3712051d16c7977a680fd50a2bd53352  
(10)   MS-MPPE-Send-Key =  
0x5ccf08fba6d8803a9ac0478c8b02bd8c9ea5829c6c3d389410eed4f36fb06692  
(10)   EAP-Message = 0x030c0004  
(10)   Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000  
(10)   User-Name = "guest123"  
(10) Finished request  
Waking up in 4.8 seconds.  
(0) Cleaning up request packet ID 42 with timestamp +29  
(1) Cleaning up request packet ID 43 with timestamp +29  
(2) Cleaning up request packet ID 44 with timestamp +29  
(3) Cleaning up request packet ID 45 with timestamp +29  
(4) Cleaning up request packet ID 46 with timestamp +29  
(5) Cleaning up request packet ID 47 with timestamp +29  
(6) Cleaning up request packet ID 48 with timestamp +29  
(7) Cleaning up request packet ID 49 with timestamp +29  
(8) Cleaning up request packet ID 50 with timestamp +29  
(9) Cleaning up request packet ID 51 with timestamp +29  
    (10)) Cleaning up request packet ID 52 with timestamp +29  
Ready to process requests
```

#### Expected result:

```
(Master1) # show user mac 44:39:c4:59:e5:64  
Name: guest123, IP: 192.168.16.23, MAC: 44:39:c4:59:e5:64, Age: 00:00:05  
Role: labguest (how: ROLE_DERIVATION_DOT1X_SDR)
```

#### Actual result:

```
(Master1) # show user mac 44:39:c4:59:e5:64  
Name: guest123, IP: 192.168.16.23, MAC: 44:39:c4:59:e5:64, Age: 00:00:05  
Role: authenticated (how: ROLE_DERIVATION_DOT1X)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to reformat your question to increase its readability.

Comment: I appreciate the edit.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem was they way I enabled EAP/TTLS/mschapv2. I followed steps from https://www.packet6.com/install-freeradius-ubuntu-server/. I tried with freeradius 2.2.8 and 3.0.15. I also tried with file-based users and postgresql, not relevant. Could the lack of fresh certificates pertain to these symptoms?

Comment: More attempts at resolution: Fresh build, FreeRADIUS 3.0.15 / Ubuntu server 16.04.3. Ditched questionable EAP setup. Here are the only changes from a default FreeRADIUS configuration: added client, added a user, and created new certificates (updating mods-enabled with the new password).

Comment: For the user, tried two syntaxes for reply AVPs:

Comment: guest23    Cleartext-Password := "guest123"                                      Service-Type = Framed-User,                                                              Framed-Filter-Id = "labguest"

Comment: **or** guest23 Cleartext-Password := "guest123" Filter-Id = "labguest"

Comment: In each case, simple CLI tests from FreeRADIUS or the Aruba controller pass (and show the returned AVP Filter-Id = labguest, but authenticated user guest123 is assigned the default role "authenticated". The Aruba CLI "aaa test-server" diag also indicates "Microsoft  MS-CHAP2-Success".

Comment: This post can be dropped if that makes sense to the admin or your community. I suspect this is an Aruba issue, and opened a ticket at Aruba TAC. If it had been a FreeRADIUS configuration/troubleshooting issue, it now appears that this is not the place for it. Thanks.

Comment: I have to assume this is an ArubaOS / NAS issue. FreeRADIUS authenticates fine but its returned attributes including Filter-Id and the Aruba VSAs are ignored at the NAS. I suspect Aruba/HPE doesn't feel compelled to fully support FreeRADIUS, for whatever reason. On the FreeRADIUS side, the GPL also leaves caveats (such as no guarantee about "merchantability and fitness for a specific purpose"). I will continue to use FreeRADIUS in my lab, with the understanding of the limitations. I know anecdotally that FreeRADIUS continues to be used with Aruba, despite these issues.

Answer (score 1):

I posted to the Aruba Airheads blog, and then opened a case with Aruba/HPE support. After analyzing logs and packet capture, the Aruba/HPE support engineer said,

"I would like to inform you that I went through the packet captures and I have attached the screenshots from the same based on what we observed;
As seen in the CP-Accept screenshot, we see the Radius Accept, for when the user was authenticating with Captive Portal. We see in the accept packet, that the server is sending the attribute 'labguest' to the controller for the user role to be assigned.

In the case of Dot1x-Accept screenshot, we do not see any attribute being sent by the server in the accept packet for when the user was authenticating with dot1x authentication.

**Please check on the server end if we need to enable sending attribute for MSCHAPv2 along with the PAP protocol, or if there are any specific configurations on the server that are handling the attributes to be sent based on the authentication type.**"

I then posted to the FreeRADIUS user list. Response:

**“The solution is to move the "files" module to before "eap".  Edit sites-enabled/default.   Look at the "authorize" section.”**

**That works. Excerpt of edited sites-enabled/default:**

```
#  
#  This module takes care of EAP-MD5, EAP-TLS, and EAP-LEAP  
#  authentication.  
#  
#  It also sets the EAP-Type attribute in the request  
#  attribute list to the EAP type from the packet.  
#  
#  The EAP module returns "ok" or "updated" if it is not yet ready  
#  to authenticate the user.  The configuration below checks for  
#  "ok", and stops processing the "authorize" section if so.  
#  
#  Any LDAP and/or SQL servers will not be queried for the  
#  initial set of packets that go back and forth to set up  
#  TTLS or PEAP.  
#  
#  The "updated" check is commented out for compatibility with  
#  previous versions of this configuration, but you may wish to  
#  uncomment it as well; this will further reduce the number of  
#  LDAP and/or SQL queries for TTLS or PEAP.  
#  
files  
eap {  
    ok = return  
#       updated = return  
}  

#  
#  Pull crypt'd passwords from /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow,  
#  using the system API's to get the password.  If you want  
#  to read /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow directly, see the  
#  mods-available/passwd module.  
#  
# unix  

#  
#  Read the 'users' file.  In v3, this is located in  
#  raddb/mods-config/files/authorize  
#   files
```

**Tests from Aruba controller:**

```
(Master1) #aaa test-server mschapv2 radius1 guest123 guest123 verbose  

Authentication Successful  
Processing time (ms) : 6.407  
Attribute value pairs in request  
--------------------------------  
Vendor     Attribute           Value  
------     ---------           -----  
           NAS-IP-Address      192.168.18.254  
           NAS-Port-Id         0  
           NAS-Port-Type       Wireless-IEEE802.11  
           User-Name           guest123  
           Service-Type        Login-User  
           Calling-Station-Id  0.0.0.0  
           Called-Station-Id   000B86BE91F0  
Microsoft  MS-CHAP-Challenge   \032\241\007[\002(\\321j5\001v\221lf\236  
Microsoft  MS-CHAP2-Response  
Aruba      Aruba-Essid-Name  
Aruba      Aruba-Location-Id   N/A  
Aruba      Aruba-AP-Group      N/A  
Aruba      Aruba-Device-Type  
           Message-Auth        I\365\262\357\365o{s\264\270\246\022Cz\264-  
           PW_RADIUS_ID        H  
           Rad-Length          199  
Attribute value pairs in response  
---------------------------------  
Vendor     Attribute                  Value  
------     ---------                  -----  
           Service-Type               Framed-User  
           Filter-Id                  labguest  
Microsoft  MS-CHAP2-Success  
Microsoft  MS-MPPE-Recv-Key           \205g8\374\333\260\031\306\3379\321\220\273\273\355\024\277\210Q\003\226\004M>\372\307p6\273&\322\231N\253  
Microsoft  MS-MPPE-Send-Key           \215\277d\301f\207A\215!\376\345.\324\177BM\364\310\251p\263\224\315 \012\001\035:\327\253\314\016\026\243  
Microsoft  MS-MPPE-Encryption-Policy  
Microsoft  MS-MPPE-Encryption-Types  
           PW_RADIUS_ID               H  
           Rad-Length                 195  
           PW_RADIUS_CODE             \002  
           PW_RAD_AUTHENTICATOR       }\203!\353\244}\215,\216\203J]\027\247\325\272  

(Master1) # show user mac  fc:c2:de:13:d6:15  

Name: guest123, IP: 192.168.16.3, MAC: fc:c2:de:13:d6:15, Age: 00:00:00  
Role: labguest (how: ROLE_DERIVATION_DOT1X_SDR), ACL: 71/0  
Authentication: Yes, status: successful, method: 802.1x, protocol: EAP-PEAP, server: radius1  
Authentication Servers: dot1x authserver: radius1, mac authserver:  
Bandwidth = No Limit  
Bandwidth = No Limit  
Role Derivation: ROLE_DERIVATION_DOT1X_SDR  
VLAN Derivation: Default VLAN
```

**Note that the edit to sites-enabled/default was after a clean FreeRADIUS install, not a correction to any monkeying.**

Answer (score 0):

In case this Attribute is set by a radius server to which the freeradius has to proxy, you have to modify the files:

mods-config/attr_filter/pre-proxy and post-proxy

adding among the attributes that you have to proxy also the:

Filter-Id =* ANY